# Throwing exceptions for error results in consumed APIs

Tags: php, exception

Do you write specific `Exception`s for error responses of the APIs you use?

e.g.:

```
class SmsServiceException extends Exception
{

}

class SmsServiceSendException extends SmsServiceException
{

}
```

Is there a specific built in exception in PHP for this situation? As there is one for invalid arguments `InvalidArgumentException`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends:

Sometimes could be usefull to pass some API specific data along with the exceptions ( for example if the API has some specific data that should be reported in the error messages ). In these cases writing a custom exception handler is the right thing to do, but there isn't a specific rule by witch you have to write a specific exception class for every API you use

There are no built in exception in PHP for this situation

Answer (score 1):

You're good to go when it comes to this exception.
PHP has some native exceptions but these do not refer to any non-built-in php problem.

It is quite a common mistake to miss an argument, thus to throw an exception PHP needs something but when doing your own things, creating classes you can freely create exceptions as well since many of your ideas will not have a default exception in PHP.

You could on the other hand write an exception class for the entire API and then pass in the name of the module to edit the exception creating 1 "flexible" exception. This does make for abit less readable code tho so keep that in mind ;)